# Reinitialize javascript function from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to solve a problem with my advertising skin.

I have a website with a scroll to fixed headerbar, and I have also an advertising skin that set a margin top when the adv is present.

To load the skin I use a javascript with google dfp as ad server. The javascript code is something like this but to embed the adv in my page Google DFP use iframe, so in my webpage I have an iframe with this code in the head of the iframe.

The iframe look for the parent windows and change the attributes of my website.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
var parent = $(window.parent.document);
var parent_body = parent.find('body');
var parent_pad = parent.find('.padded-container');
parent_body.css("backgroundImage", "url('%%VIEW_URL_UNESC%%%%FILE:JPG1%%')")
           .css("backgroundPosition", "top center")
           .css("backgroundRepeat", "no-repeat")
           .css("backgroundAttachment", "fixed")
           .css("margin-top", 100);
parent_pad.before('<a id="sitewrap" href="%%CLICK_URL_ESC%%%%DEST_URL%%" target="_blank" style="display:block;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;cursor:pointer"></a>');
});
</script>
```

Everything is working fine, when my website load the iframe adv the js code in the header of the embedded iframe change the css attribute of my website and the skin appear.

The problem is the navigation bar of my website, a sticky navigation loaded before the iframe.
This is the invocation code.

```
stickyNavigation : function stickyNavigation() {

            if ($(window).scrollTop() > navTop) {
                $container.addClass('fixed-nav');
            } else {
                $container.removeClass('fixed-nav');
            }
        },
```

where

```
$nav = $('.site-nav');
navTop = $nav.offset().top;
```

The iframe is loaded after the page, so the `$nav.offset().top` value doesn't consider the 100px of margin.

If I write in browser console `window.headerManager.init();` I can reinitialize the script when the skin is loaded, but of course I need to add `window.headerManager.init();` in the js code I load on my adserver, and from the iframe head I cannot call `window.headerManager.init();` because `window` is the window of the iframe, and I need to catch the parent window.

How can I solve this issue?

**updated**

Comment: You might want to learn something about "chaining" in jQuery to save having to repeatedly built the same jQuery object over and over.

Comment: @jfriend00 edited, better now?

Comment: That's the idea except your syntax has errors (no semi-colons in the middle of chaining).

Comment: done. And for my issue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.  Your issue seems to have something to do with an iframe and `window.headerManager.init()`, yet you don't show the iframe, the `window.headerManager.init()` code or where you're trying to call that code or describe anything about what "it doesn't work" means.  I think you should reduce your question to only things that are directly relevant to your question and include the important things that describe your problem in detail.

Comment: I hope that now is more clear... sorry

Answer (score 0):

I've found that iframe to parent page communication is typically easier via postMessage. You can set up a listener in the parent page so that when your iframe posts, you can reinit your method.